# Can Congress make certain construction projects immune from litigation?

Tags: united-states, law

In an article about the [Joe Manchin pipeline deal](https://www.propublica.org/article/manchin-gas-pipeline-climate-change-bill) I've noticed an interesting detail:

> The provisions, according to the summary, will “require the relevant agencies to take all necessary actions to permit the construction and operation of the Mountain Valley Pipeline” and would shift jurisdiction “over any further litigation” to a different court, the D.C. Circuit Court of Appeals.

Could Congress pass a law mandating that a certain project (such a pipeline) is completely immune from litigation? So instead of merely shifting the jurisdiction, could they mandate that no one may start a lawsuit about the pipeline in the first place? If yes, are there historical examples of such legislation?

Comment: My understanding is that you are asking "Can congress legislate a law disallowing/banning lawsuits?"  Is that possible or desirable? If so, we only need two branches of the government. :)

Comment: More fundamental version of your question, "Can any branch of government, pass a law, sign an executive order, or adjudicate a ruling on a case, with the implicit support of another branch, to cut the other branch out altogether?" Keeping in mind ofcourse, that all of those branches are eventually balanced out by the ultimate power - the People.

Comment: I suppose an example of this happening is DACA. An executive order was signed. The judiciary has ruled that the order cannot be reversed. It is now effectively de facto 'law'. Congress was left out of the process completely. So there is precedent...

Comment: I suppose another example might be [sovereign immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_immunity), which is effectively the executive and legislative branches teaming up to keep the judiciary out the action.

Comment: @ouflak The court didn't say that it couldn't be reversed, they said that the Trump administration didn't give appropriate justification for reversing it. And it wasn't immune from litigation, since it went through that litigation.

Comment: @Barmar, "And it wasn't immune from litigation..." Correct. My example is that of the Executive branch and Judicial branch creating a law, excluding Congress entirely - the basic concept being that two branches team up (implicitly or explicitly) to create a law, entity, or the like that is effectively untouchable by the third branch of government. I can't immediately think of any examples of the judiciary and legislative branch corroborating in such a fashion against the executive. A first place to look would be overridden presidential vetoes that were subsequently upheld by the Supreme Court.

Comment: [Related Q&A (possibly even a duplicate)](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/63125/how-far-does-congressional-judicial-stripping-extend) about Congress's jurisdiction stripping abilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Q: Can Congress make certain construction projects immune from litigation?*

Apparently, yes (IANAL).

[Congress’s Power over Courts: Jurisdiction Stripping and the Rule of *Klein*](https://sgp.fas.org/crs/misc/R44967.pdf) discusses a number of separation-of-power cases that began with *United States v. Klein*. These cases involve Congress changing the law such that the Court should rule in a particular way.

##### *Patchak v. Zinke*

[This case appears closest to the subject of *construction projects immune from litigation*.]

> *Patchak* involved a challenge to the Department of the Interior’s (DOI’s) decision in 2005 to place a tract of land in Wayland Township, Michigan—known as the “Bradley Property”—in trust under the Indian Reorganization Act (IRA) for the Match-E-Be-Nash-She-Wish Band of Pottawatomi Indians (known as the “Gun Lake Tribe”). After the Gun Lake Tribe began building a casino on the Bradley Property, David Patchak, who lives in Wayland Township, sued officials from the Bureau of Indian Affairs under the Administrative Procedure Act (APA), asserting that the DOI lacked authority under the IRA to place the Bradley Property in trust for the Gun Lake Tribe*.

Initially, the district count found a lack of "prudential standing"; but the Supreme Court reversed and "remanded the case to the district court for resolution on the merits."

Congress then passed the *[Gun Lake Trust Land Reaffirmation Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_Lake_Trust_Land_Reaffirmation_Act)* which, among other things, "stripped federal courts of jurisdiction to hear claims related to the Bradley Property."

> Notwithstanding any other provision of law, an action (including an action pending in a Federal court as of the date of enactment of [the] Act) relating to the [Bradley Property] shall not be filed or maintained in a Federal court and shall be promptly dismissed.

The district court "concluded that it no longer had jurisdiction to hear the case because of the new law and dismissed the suit." "The D.C. Circuit affirmed, ..." and the case went back to the Supreme Court.

> In a 4-2-3 ruling authored by Justice Thomas and joined by Justices Breyer, Alito, and Kagan, a plurality of the Supreme Court concluded that the jurisdiction-stripping provision of the Gun Lake Act does not violate Article III of the Constitution. Together, with the separate votes of Justices Ginsburg and Sotomayor concurring in the judgment, the Court affirmed the D.C. Circuit’s ruling.

> Justice Thomas’s plurality opinion distilled Klein and its progeny as creating the following rule: “Congress violates Article III when it compels[] findings or results under old law. But Congress does not violate Article III when it changes the law.”

Even the following dissent makes stronger the case that Congress can prevent litigation when the law is enacted prior to any litigation.

> Chief Justice Roberts, joined by Justices Kennedy and Gorsuch, dissented. ... Chief Justice Roberts would have held “that Congress exercises the judicial
> power when it manipulates jurisdictional rules to decide the outcome of a particular pending case.”